# Using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter in a multi-threaded-environment

Tags: c#, json, multithreading, serialization

Throughout my project I have a singleton service class that takes care of (de)serializing, with something like this:

```
_setting = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter>() { new MyConverter() },
    TraceWriter = new Iov.Common.Json.TraceWriter(),
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
    SerializationBinder = binder,
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate,
};
```

The service will be used in a multi-threaded environment, i.e. several (de)serializing tasks will - at the same time - use the above `JsonSerializerSettings` with my custom `JsonConverter`.

Up to now the converter has been stateless, but for deserializing I'm considering tracking the state, i.e. current position within the JSON object, child/parent-relationships. The converter would need to store/cache its results (basically in the `ReadJson` override) in some kind of stack/list.

All (de)serialize calls are wrapped in the mentioned service's methods, so I could easily implement using a new instance of the `JsonSerializerSettings` with my custom `JsonConverter` for each call.

Assuming my initial assumption is correct that the `JsonConverter` is thread-agnostic and therefore multithreading-safe *as long as its stateless*, my question is: can I rely on the `JsonConverter` to always deserialize objects in the same order?

I know that the order in which members are populated is not defined (as the order in a `Dictionary` is not), but will it always deserialize "from leaf to branch"?